# Background-size IE7 & 8 CSS hack

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, background-image, background-size

I know background-size isn't supported for IE7 and IE8. I also know there is a solution of using AlphaImageLoader as below:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
        src='image.gif', sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
             src='image.gif', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

But unfortunately its not working. Any suggestions?

Here is my code in CSS:

```
.useBGImage { 
    background-image: url('../img/BGImage.gif'); 
    background-size: 400px 50px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
            src='../img/BGImage.gif', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
                 src='../img/BGImage.gif', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

The original size of the image is 400px * 70px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use one of the available polyfill libraries to solve this.

There are two that I can think of which would fit the bill:

- [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)
- https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Of these, CSS3Pie covers a load more functionality than just `background-size`, so would be good if you're also doing similar `filter` styles for gradients, etc. The other one is a one-trick polyfill just for this specific feature.

Both are known to work well, so pick whichever you prefer, and throw away those ugly `filter` styles.

Comment: Hi @Spudley! Thanks for your suggestion. Yes I also thought of using CSS3Pie. That was my last option, but its not acceptable to client, so they have agreed to keep the image as it is without shrinking! :)

Comment: Hmm, pity that CSS3Pie isn't acceptable. Would love to know the client's reasoning for that; it's hard to see a justification that would actually stand up to logical argument. But clients can be like that, and if that's how it is, then it sounds like you've got the right solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to microsoft's own documentation `sizingMethod='scale'`

> Scale
>           Stretches or shrinks the image to fill the borders of the object.

As you can see *scale* is a poor choice of words to use since it doesn't really "scale" it merely stretches and/or shrinks the image to fit the boundaries of its container.

To effectively scale an image proportionately it is recommended that you remove the height and width of the image in the HTML markup.

Then use this as your CSS...

```
.useBGImage {
    background-image: url('../img/BGImage.gif');  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: auto; /* required for IE8 */
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kuya! This solution didn't work for me. Thanks btw.